Infinite Redirect between GitHub and GoDaddy
I'm having an issue with a website that I am hosting on GitHub with a Domain from GoDaddy.
The site is located at griftertheband.com
Sometimes, I get the "Safari can't open the page because too many redirects occurred" message when I try to access the site on my iphone. In the Chrome browser, I get teh error "This page isn’t workingjon424.github.io redirected you too many times."
I have followed the instructions for "Managing a custom domain for your GitHub Pages site" found in the GitHub docs here: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site.
The code for the site lives on GitHub. It is a fairly simple repo here: https://github.com/jon424/grifter with the following structure:
/img
about.html
favicon.ico
index.html

Under GitHub Pages, I see that my site is live at http://griftertheband.com/
Under Custom Domain, I have "griftertheband.com"
There is a message that says "DNS Check in Progress", which is strange because I know that this check was successful in the past, it just seems that it is stuck in the "checking" process right now:

On the GoDaddy side, I have a lot of DNS Records for griftertheband.com. This is what my DNS records page looks like (three screenshots for pagination):



Does it look like I'm missing anything that could prevent this infinite re-direct from happening? Thanks for any info.

There are a few things happening, but I am pretty sure you missed this part of the docs:

To publish a user site, you must create a repository owned by your
personal account that's named .github.io.

I see you have a repo named https://github.com/jon424/jon424.github.io.  To explain what's happening:
If you access jon424.github.io directly, it serves the content from jon424.github.io.  I can see this is working from an older project.
If you access jon424.github.io/pizza, GitHub will check jon424.github.io for a pizza folder.  If it finds one, it will serve content from there.  If it does not find one, which is what's happening here, it will check for a repo named pizza owned by user jon424.
Since it found one, it will serve content from there.  It also looks for a CNAME file, and it finds one, which redirects it to griftertheband.com.
Your DNS settings have a CNAME which redirects to jon424.github.io.  By requesting griftertheband.com, your request is redirected through GitHub's service, which attaches the /griftertheband URI since your original request was for griftertheband.com.  Upon reaching it, it then redirects back to griftertheband.com.
I don't know exactly what your issue is, because the DNS pictures you've attached are a bit confusing - I don't know what half of that stuff is.  But I noticed that https are getting redirected to http and you may have set that up incorrectly.
I would try to take a step back and try:

Delete the jon424.github.io repo (archive the project under a different name if you want to keep the music theory quiz code around)
Delete the grifter repo, move its code to a new jon424.github.io repo.
Remove ALL your DNS settings for griftertheband.com
Set up an A record from your DNS provider pointing griftertheband.com to jon424.github.io
Do not worry about the www CNAME yet, verify that https://griftertheband.com returns the page in the GitHub repo and that griftertheband.com does too (and uses https).  If it's redirecting to http://griftertheband.com then figure out how to get that working next.
Add back the www CNAME (if desired, I think www is on the way out and does not really need to be supported) and verify that https://griftertheband.com, https://www.griftertheband.com, griftertheband.com, and www.griftertheband.com all resolve to https://griftertheband.com and serve the correct content.
Add back your other DNS settings if they are needed for other services.



thanks so much for this incredibly helpful, thoughtful response!

I'm on step 6. I'm trying to add back the CNAME, but I'm getting this error saying that the 'www' Name is conflicting with another record. I DO of course have another record with Type: A | Name: www | Data: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ... Data is the IP for jon424.github.io. For my attempted CNAME record I tried adding: Type:  CNAME | Name: www | Data: griftertheband.com  .... Is there another value I can use for the CNAME record? The site is loading, though, at: https://griftertheband.com/ , though https is not in use.

@Jon It looks like https is in use now, and that https://www... redirects to the non-www link.  But I noticed a few things,
If I open a new tab and type griftertheband.com I get sent to https://griftertheband.com/ (good)
https://www.griftertheband.com -> https://griftertheband.com (good)
www.griftertheband.com -> http:/griftertheband.com (not good)
http://griftertheband.com -> http://griftertheband.com (not good)
I think you can fix both of those by setting up an http -> https redirect (which would make http://www.griftertheband.com go first to non www  then to https.

Sorry, don't have time to think about your question right now so I hope you can figure it out.
Also not sure if you know this, but https protects against data being transferred being intercepted (e.g. account logins or credit card info).  Right now, you aren't exposing the user to any danger by using http, so if you don't want to invest more time and effort right now into trying to fix it, that would be an option.  Downside is that browsers will warn users and they might get scared even though there is no real risk.  & most users will access it with https by default so it's probably fine.
